# Interpreting $G^2$ with respect to $\chi^2$

Tags: r, logistic, chi-squared-test, deviance

I'm analyzing a data set with three categorical variables, two of which are binary, the last of which takes on $5$ possible values. As such, when trying to find a relationship (if any) between the two binary variables (putting aside the final one for now), I utilized the method logistic regression (I'm working in R, so plugging it all in isn't too bad). I then ran the same regression now applying the $5$-category categorical variable as a bucket, i.e. I divided the data set into $5$ parts and ran the same regression as before, just on each bucket separately. (This $5$-tier variable is income quintile of the subjects, for clarity.) The results of my testing are below:

[image]

R outputs null deviance when you run logistic regressions, and from what I understand, that is typically denoted as $G^2$. I also ran $\chi^2$ tests for independence on each of my contingency tables (I have $6$: one for the total population, and then one for each quintile of income). I suppose my question is this: if I know that my $\chi^2$ value is above the significance level, which means I should reject the null hypothesis of independence, does that mean that my $G^2$ also implies the same information? I'm rather new to deviance calculations (I've seen $\chi^2$ loads before, but never $G^2$, or logistic regressions for that matter), and so a bit of clarification on the relationship between these two statistics would be sincerely appreciated.

Additionally (and distinctly), it seems that my data implies that on a macro level there is some dependence between the two variables of interest. However, when we inspect it by income group, this relationship seems to be lost/more muddled (for small enough $\alpha$). I'm familiar with the concept of Simpson's Paradox, but this seems to be slightly different than that. Is there any name for what I've encountered here? Any suggestions/information/references would be immensely appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G^2$ and $X^2$ are very similar. They have the same null hypothesis and they have power against the same set of alternatives. More than that, when the departure from the null is not very large and the sample size is not very small, they are numerically close together. (technical phrase: locally asymptotically equivalent)

$G^2$ is the likelihood ratio test: it compares the loglikelihood for the independence model to the loglikelihood without the assumption of independence

$X^2$ is the score test: it compares the derivative of the loglikelihood for the independence model to the derivative of the loglikelihood without the assumption of independence (which is zero).

The [answer to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/493967/asymptotic-equivalence-of-likelihood-ratio-staitistic-and-wald-statistic) compares the two testing strategies in a more general setting